Problem of getting resource using getResource()
I need to get a resource FXML file in a Java project. Here's my code:
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    try {
//        System.out.println(getClass());
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/org/example/ooplibrary/View/LogInView.fxml");
        if (url == null) {
            throw new IOException("FXML file not found");
        }
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(url);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
} 

The directory structure is the following
org/
   example/
        ooplibrary/
                 Core/
                    Main.java
                 View/
                    LogInView.fxml


The getClass() works normally but when I add the getResource(), the output was always null. I have tried all the paths but it didn't work. Can anyone give me a hint?

So the start method is in class Main, correct? If yes, then what is the package for class Main?

Here is the package of Main.java:
package org.example.ooplibrary.Core;

Please try to provide a proper [mre] that demonstrates the error with the steps necessary to run the application. Also, see if How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application? and https://edencoding.com/where-to-put-resource-files-in-javafx/ help at all.

You can probe URL url = this.getClass().getResource( "/View/LogInView.fxml" );, that is Java, or JavaFx?.

What is the full path to class Main.class? Note the .class file (and not the .java file).

Place your LogInView.fxml File not in
src/main/java/org/example/ooplibrary/View/LogInView.fxml
but in
src/main/resources/org/example/ooplibrary/View/LogInView.fxml

I have already done it but it still throws the IOException

@HảiVõ Note the advice in this answer really only applies if you're using Maven or Gradle with the standard directory layout, or if you've configured your IDE to do the same. Are you using Maven or Gradle as your build tool? If yes, how are you running your application? If not, is the FXML file a descendant of a directory you've configured the IDE to see as a "resource root"? Please add this information to your question.

I use Maven as my build tool and I run the application just by compiling the Main.java which was the code I share on my post.

@HảiVõ If you're using Maven, then compiling the code should be done with Maven (e.g., mvn compile). You can have your IDE delegate build tasks to the build tool. Also, assuming this is a JavaFX application, you may want to consider applying javafx-maven-plugin. Then you can try running your application with the javafx:run goal to see if it works.
